# qextserialport strange read

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, arduino, qextserialport

Im using Window 7 x64
Problem in that that I send with Arduino on PC information, and when reading port, I receive the strange artifact of Arduino send(0000000) PC reads (0000+000) or something similar (00000+00) - (0+000000) and so on.

For an example I will show a screenshot

[image]

and

[image]

Open port

```
bool MainWindow::openPort()
{

    QString strPort = LineConnect->currentText();
    port = new QextSerialPort(strPort, QextSerialPort::EventDriven);

    if (port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered) == true) {


        port->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
        port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
        port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
        port->setStopBits(STOP_1);
        port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
        port->setTimeout(100);
        port->waitForReadyRead(10);
        port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered);
        connect(port,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
        INFO_conn->append("port "+ port->portName() + " opened..");
        INFO_conn->append("port " + port->portName() + " reading..");

        return true;
    } else {
        INFO_conn->append("port " + port->portName() + " error connection..");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Read data

```
void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
        /*first option read data*/
        QByteArray msg = port->readAll();
        int size = msg.size();
        QString data = "Data: " + msg + " size: " + QString::number(size);
        INFO_conn->append(data);

        /*second option read data*/
    //    char data[1024];
    //    QTextStream out(stdout);

    //    out << "data received: ";
    //    int bytesRead = port->read(data, 1024);
    //    data[bytesRead] = '\0';
    //    out << data << " (" << bytesRead << " bytes)" << endl;
    //    //QString messRead = "data received: " + data +" "+ bytesRead + " bytes";
    //    INFO_conn->append(data);

}
```

send data arduino for PC

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);

   .....
}
void loop()
{
   Serial.print(K38);
   Serial.print(K40);
   Serial.print(K42);
   Serial.print(K44);
   Serial.print(K46);
   Serial.print(K48);
   Serial.print(K50);

   or

   Serial.print("0000000"); // result same

}
```

I can't understand in what there can be a problem, tried everything. 
Examples from QexSerialPort library read too most. 
Need help.Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should consider using QtSerialPort. I cannot mention any reason for using QextSerialPort in new code these days.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest debugging your serial port code using a serial terminal application ([Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), Hyperterminal).  Connect a serial terminal application to the Arduino and see if get the output you expect.  Also connect it to your Qt application and see if you can send text to your Qt application and get sane output.  You should be able to tell better if the problem is with the code on the Arduino or on the PC.

Comment: I arrived according to your advice and received the following result
1) PUTTY connect arduino port on an output everything is normal
(http://rghost.ru/47772883.view)
2)  it is a little more difficult to connect to Qt application therefore it was necessary to create 2 virtual ports and to use them: 1 on an output 2 on an input. On an output I received
http://rghost.ru/47772929.view
according to the total I and don't know in what there can be a problem. Probably any mistiming, probably not correctly I read out data (though it is very strange as and examples in the library read as)

Comment: I think I better understand your issue.  If you are trying to get the same message length received every time.  You could add a delay after the Arduino sends the data out, and have the PC wait for the message for a short period of time.  Another alternative would be to put a delimiting character in the Arduino output like a newline, and then on the PC process the data a line at a time.

Comment: Yes of course I tried to put time delays on arduino to 5000ms the result simply changes in that range that I wrote in the top (00-00000)... () also behaves approximately cyclically. And it isn't clear if I need to read out in real-time data why I shall do a time delay.

As for option to make da's delimiter it is good option solving this problem, I have a function which does it, but it not a solution and deception. 
At the end of this week or at the beginning of following, there will be an opportunity to ask the person who knows on this subject than I more, the response will be probably found.